I want to create a validation attribute, that has a IUserService and will check if user with the same email already exists, in C# ASP.NET
I'm a newbie in ASP.NET. I want to create my custom validation attribute to check if a user with the same email already exists.
So, I need to assign an IUserService through the constructor and dependency injection. After that, I want to use that IUserService method in the validation method to check if the user already exists.
This is the code for my custom attribute:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EmailAlreadyExists : ValidationAttribute
{
    public new string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    readonly IUserService _userService;

    public EmailAlreadyExists(IUserService userService) 
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string email = (string)value;

        if (_userService.CheckIfUserWithTheEmailAlreadyExists(email)) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
          UserStringConstants.UserAlreadyExistsErrorMessage, name);
    }
}

And I try to use my custom attribute here:
namespace WebApiForHikka.WebApi.Dto.Users;

public class UserRegistrationDto
{
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = SharedStringConstants.EmailIsntFormatedCorrectlyErrorMessage)]
    [EmailAlreadyExists()]
    [Required]
    public required string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(UserStringConstants.SimplePasswordRegExpression, ErrorMessage = UserStringConstants.SimplePasswordErrorMessage)]
    public required string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public required string Role { get; set; }
}

But I get an error which tells me that I don't have a constructor  with zero params.
By the way, all my dtos are in a library, because of it, I inject my dependency in a project for Web API controller.
So, is it possible to use dependency injection with a custom validation attribute?

Careful; hackers can use the response from such a thing to work out valid emails on your system (and then combined with a breached email/password list from another hack, perhaps break into yours because humans reuse passwords). Better to neither confirm nor deny, but instead if they try sign up with the same email, just treat it as a forgot password but display it as if it's a signup ("we've sent you an email...") etc. SImilar for forgot password, annoying as it is, "if that email address is registered with us we'll send you a code"
